# Subtracting Geometry?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have two models - we'll say a sphere and hollow cylinder - that I'm working with.  Effectively, I want to 'subtract' the hollow-cylinder shape from the sphere.  I know from certain orientations (the top of the sphere) this is fairly easily done, just a matter of deleting and creating new faces.  However, from other orientations the edges/geometry doesn't line up so easily.  Is there an automatic (or at least, not terribly difficult/manual) way to 'subtract' one mesh from another?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use a *[Boolean modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html)*.

For example, adding a boolean modifier to a sphere with the operation set to *Difference*, the parts of the sphere which intersect the object specified in the modifier will be subtracted.

[image]

As a bonus, a quick way to select an object for a modifier (or anywhere a similar selection interface is used) is by pressing <kbd>E</kbd> while hovering over the object selection drop down and clicking on the desired object in the 3D view.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for all the answers so far - expect more questions, I'm still learning. ;)

Comment: @David I'm afraid it's not the first.. I'm working on it though :)