# How to intersect objects and delete leftover internal planes?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I'm trying to find a simple way to create vertices where two objects intersect and delete the leftover internal planes + then join the meshes so that I have one hollow mesh to sculpt.

The reason I need to know this is that on my first sculpt I just joined the meshes, but it didn't create vertices at the intersecting points so when I went to sculpt it just overlapped the meshes as you can see here in the neck.

[image: neck dilema]

Here is what I am working on now, it needs to be 1 hollow mesh

[image: outside]

Comment: You can join them in one object and use intersect tool while changing to self intersect in operator panel and then delete internal faces.

Comment: @gandalf3 The other posts answer uses the boolean technique, while denis here has described a simpler process.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12311/subtracting-geometry?lq=1

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Select the objects and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join them into one object, change to edit mode and select the meshes you want to intersect, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and select **Intersect (Knife)** from the menu and change to **Self Intersect** in operator panel.

[image]

After the operation is done, intersecting edges will be selected and you can mark them as seams <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>>Mark Seam, then select internal faces using <kbd>L</kbd> button when hovering with the mouse cursor over internal faces while in face selection mode.

[image]

Comment: **Update:** Figured out, it doesn't work on planes without a thickness. Apply a Solidify modifier to the whole mesh of planes and the technique described by Denis works without crashing the program. Bools doesn't like flat surfaces apparently.

Comment: So, funny thing- when I CTR- F there is no Intersect tool listed. It goes straight from Solidify to Wire Frame. Any ideas?

Comment: @vbsargent My guess is that you have an older version of Blender. The intersect tool was introduced in 2.72 or 2.73 I believe. If that isn't it, please ask a separate question, and you should probably include screenshots of your UI with the _Faces_ menu open.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote "Update: Figured out, it doesn't work on planes without a thickness. Apply a Solidify modifier to the whole mesh of planes and the technique described by Denis works without crashing the program. Bools doesn't like flat surfaces apparently."

You can use 'Weld Edges into Faces' function for flat surfaces. 
1. go to edit mode
2. select all edges which share one face 
3. with 'shift' select an edge or edges which you want to intersect. they need to be without faces
4. press 'Weld Edges into Faces' in Face menu

Everything should be coplanar (lay in the same plane) for this operation