# How to merge seperated Edge into Mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

I have a seperated Edge Loop that intersects with another mesh.

Here a simple example:

[image]

I tried *Boolean*, *Knife Project* and *Intersect Tool* ([this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28577/19287)) without succes.
My last idea is to subdived the edges of the cube, position the vertices and merge them one by one. Is there any better solution?

How can i make it one mesh so that the *Cube* contains the *Edge Loop*?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Cut away all the connecting edges between the top and the bottom of the cube. (check the edge select -> remove only edges)
2. Join both meshes.
3. Select remaining edgeloop on top (top side of the former cube).
4. Select the edgeloop to introduce.
5. "Bridge Edgeloops".
6. Select the edgeloop you introduced.
7. Select remaining edgeloop on the bottom.
8. "Bridge Edgeloops".

Comment: simple and good solution. So as I please.thx

Comment: It could also be nice to cut the cube with the edge, but i wasnt able to manage that.

Comment: You can extrude your edgeloop outwards (Extrude, Enter , scale +shift Z), join with the other mesh, use "Intersect (Knife)", remove doubles and clean everything up