# How can I combine 4 intersecting/converging polygons?

Tags: modeling

So I really can't figure out a good way to combine these at the convergence point.
[image]

I guess I should also add would it even be worth combining if it is for game use or some sort of production work?

Comment: try this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28574/simple-way-to-creating-vertices-at-intersecting-planes-and-deleting-leftover-int/28577

Comment: Denis this helped, but gives me an undesired outcome. I think I'll just need to leave it as is.

Comment: There is an addon called "[pipe joints](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_Pipe_Joints)". Not updated anymore but still usable.

Comment: Unless you're concerned about excess mesh (which can slow things down when they get too much) you shouldn't need to worry about it.