# How to select leaves on a sapling-addon tree when selecting their branch?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, sapling-addon

I'd like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad +</kbd> in edit mode to select branches and leaves on a tree generated using the sapling add-on. I have a workflow to connect all of the branches to the trunk. However, I'm not able to find a way to connect the leaves to the mesh so they can be selected along with the branches.

Is there a way to generate the model or modify the models so that leaves can be selected as vertices along a branch are selected using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad +</kbd>?

---

**Example:**

1. Add a sapling tree to a model. Enable 'bevel' and enable 'show leaves'.

[image]

2. Convert the tree curve into a mesh in object mode.
3. Go into edit mode. The mesh for branches and the trunk are part of the same object and intersect, but are not connected.

[image]

4. In edit mode, select all vertices, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and select 'intersect (knife)' and on the toolbar select 'Self Intersect' and deselect 'Separate'. This will create merge the meshes and they will be connected at the intersections. Since it is connected, it is now possible to select trunk and branches using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad +</kbd>. (See [stack exchange question] discussing the process[3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28574/simple-way-to-creating-vertices-at-intersecting-planes-and-deleting-leftover-int/28577#28577))

[image]

5. If connected vertices are continued to be selected, the leaves are not selected. **Is there a way to modify the leaves so as the branch is selected, the leaves are also selected?**

[image]

---

Sample blender file: [image]

Comment: I see no obvious way to do that unless said leaves are physically connected to the corresponding branch. You could go and create vertex groups for each branch and assign them to the leaves as well but that requires lots of manual labor.

Comment: This could probably be scripted, but I'm not aware of a non-programmatic way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leaves can be connected to the sapling mesh through the following steps.

1) In object mode, select the tree and the leaves.

[image]

2) Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join the meshes.

[image]

3) Enter edit mode and select all using <kbd>A</kbd>.

[image]

4) Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and select 'Intersect (knife)' and make sure the Separate option is unselected and the Source is 'Self intersect'.

[image]

5) Now the mesh is fully connected, including leaves. Selecting a vertex and using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>numpad +</kbd> will select all of the connected elements.

[image]