# Retreiving only surface intersection between two objects

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects

I have the following model in Blender:

[image: CubeandCone]

I want to retrieve the intersect faces between the cone and cube.

When using the intersect boolean modifier I end up with the following object:

[image: IntersectCubeandCone]

The solution posted [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28574/simple-way-to-creating-vertices-at-intersecting-planes-and-deleting-leftover-int) doesn't work on planes without a thickness which wont be possible for my application.

Also I am planning to repeat this operation often via a script so I am looking for a solution that would work with multiple configurations.

Thanks for your help,