# Easy way to create inset letters

Tags: modeling

I am at a new project, in which I will have stone walls with with text on them. Is there any easy way to get the writing look somewhat like this, without having to model every single letter like this?

I don't care for the font, but I do care for the triangular inset shape.

[image]

Any ideas on that would be more than welcome.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Same question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100117/modeling-v-engraved-chiseled-text?rq=1, links to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text