# How to make sharp edge bevel 3d text

Tags: text-object

I want to know how to make the 3d text like this reference image.
Like how to bevel the text like a curved triangle foom the middle of the letter.  (don't know to describe it exactly).
Thanks!
[image: https://i.pinimg.com/564x/c7/c3/1c/c7c31c8b8f8aa1dc35a6f739145ec624.jpg]

I also want to know how can I delete the middle space of the R letter, thanks!
When I connect the verticles it just fiil the whole R.
[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64980/how-to-make-a-metal-emboss/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134971/round-beveled-text

Comment: Since your reference letter "R" is quite pointy, the moonboots's answer became hard to handle very quickly ... and Duarte's link doesnt really answering the topic ... probably try this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/297332/2214 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there's any automatic way to create this kind of letter but you can try it this way.

In order to create a hole in a face you'll always need at least 2 edges that go from the inner edge to the outer edge:

[image]

Extrude up:

[image]

As for the inset, you can enable the *Mesh: Edit Mesh Tools* addon, select all and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Offset Edges > Extrude*, tweak the *Width* value in the *Operator Box*:

[image]

Move up the inset (it will still need a bit of work on its topology):

[image]

To remove the inner faces, you could use the knife (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut through, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to validate):

[image]

Then select all the edges that are perpendicular and <kbd>X</kbd> >  *Collapse Edges & Faces*:

[image]

But it may be better to keep an inner face and just make it thinner.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm new to modeling.

Can I also ask how to make the top faces to become as small as possible like combing into one edge, is that I can only move the edges close together using "G" key. 

And also want to know how to make the side view triangle to a curve triangle (like the photo red line sketch I draw, I want it to become curve and no faces on the top) Thanks!
https://imgur.com/a/8gKwjMR

Comment: @yaryar You can use Curve Object used as Bevel > Object https://imgur.com/Px0eSkx under your curve's letter properties and use the same Intersect (Knife) technique mentioned in my link I posted bellow your Question in Comments. Probably better to ask another Q, but are you sure about curvature? Your original reference (the gold R letter) use straight profile. What make it curvy is intersection of crossed faces.