y2k edged chrome font

Hey Guys,
has anyone of you an idea how I can create this sharped/ edged Type in Blender?
I am new at it and I dont know how to start the modeling or maybe to use Geo nodes?
Alot of Tutorials are out there, but only with the remash option, here the edges are all rounded and smooth

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134971/round-beveled-text https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100117/modeling-v-engraved-chiseled-text https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/296789/how-to-make-sharp-edge-bevel-3d-text https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-make-a-bevel-on-text
