# How to easily build concentric curved tubes to make layered tubes?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, scale

I have built tubes by Bezier Curve, converting to mesh, and adding solidify modifier. I want concentric tubes now. I could not directly scale the duplicated tube, which will cause it to be not concentric (as shown on the left in the Figure 1).

I have been able to duplicate the Bezier Curve and go through the process and add thicker layer (on the right of Figure 1) to make concentric tubes. But there seems to be a little gaps between the outer tube and the inner one. However, this process will not work for dynamic tubes, especially when they change locations.

Figure 2, I tried using curve modifier, but only can move or rotate it or a little shrinkage. I think I need subdivisions on the cylinders, right?

Figure 3(left), Later, I tried more subdivisions, which works good for one cylinder, but not for concentric cylinders joined together. Even I also set subdivisions for the inner cylinder.
Figure 3(right) using array modifier to elongate the cylinders and join them, add curve modifier, and separate them by loose parts. Make sure the origins of the cylinders and the curves at the same spot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A simple idea may be to make the inner tube slightly larger (overlapping the outer) and then subtract the outer tube to get a perfect fitting inner tube.

Comment: @Real Do you mean using the same bezier curve to create two tubes first?And bend them together, and then substrate?

Comment: Yes, make a larger and a smaller and subtract the larger from smaller. See [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12311/subtracting-geometry)

Comment: @Real You're right about that. I have been able to build two cylinders and add the same curve modifier to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say you try this as a solution:

Add a cylinder. Delete the top and bottom faces of it. Give it a solidify modifier. Duplicate it and scale it down by locking the Z axis until it's boundaries fit in the inner boundaries of the biger cylinder.[image]
Once you are happy with the thickness and scale apply the solidify modifier. And then hit Ctrl+A to apply scale on both the objects. Then select both of them and hit Ctrl+J to join. Then rotate them along the X axis by 90 degrees. Then go to Object>Set Origin>Origin to Geometry. Then apply the rotation. Then add in an array modifier. Set the X and Z offset to 0 and the Y offset to 1. The count on the Array Modifier will change the lenght of your object. Then add in a path.[image]
Rotate the curve on the Z axis by -270 degrees. Then add in a curve modifier on your object and select that path. Then scale that path to be as long as your object. Now if you go into edit mode on your path you can play with the verticies of your path and your mesh will be deformed.[image]

Comment: Chaudhry, thank you so much for your time in figuring this out. It seems a good method. But I still have some questions. Why do you apply array modifier? I tried your method, but not works well, as updated in the question area. By joining the cylinders, they become one, which may prevent setting two different materials, right?

Comment: @tryphena I apply the solidify modifier not the array. And I joined both the cylinders so I don't have to add the modifiers on both the objects. You can always edit the cylinders in edit mode. And for setting new materials you can just go to edit mode, and assign a new material to a specific part of a mesh.

Comment: Okay. You mentioned: "Then add in an array modifier. Set the X and Z offset to 0 and the Y offset to 1. The count on the Array Modifier will change the lenght of your object." So this is not necessary?

Comment: @tryphena this is necessary if you want a long cylinder. Or you can just go into edit mode and elongate both the cylinders.

Comment: @tryphena I'll try again and check if I forgot to add something in the answer. But if one thing is done wrong the same thing will happen as you have shown in your question. I think you did the last part of my method wrong.

Comment: @tryphena I see now what is wrong. make sure to rotate the curve on the Z axis by -180 degrees after rotating it 90 degrees. It works. In simple words make sure that your curve has a rotaation of -270 degrees.

Comment: Yousurf, I see your point in using array modifier(similar to this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3NFtRBDCV0), which gives more flexibility to the long cylinder to bend. The rotation can be implemented by changing the deform axis in curve modifier. I have some more updated in the question area.